# javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document

Tags: javadoc

Am facing an issue while running javadoc in child project. There are multiple projects and they are interdependent.

While running javadoc on childproject, I recieve below error where other project classes(dependent classes for child project) are not found in classpath. 
javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.

How can I run javadoc on childproject? Looked into javadoc options which did not help much

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some `javadoc` options may be required.

`-sourcepath` to specify different child projects/directories

`-subpackages` to specify a base package and all its subpackages recursively

See [javadoc options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDFDACB) for details.

See [javadoc examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDJBGFC) for various possible cases.